# how I can use if condition in ampl?

Tags: linear-programming, cplex, ampl

I am wondering can I use if operator in ampl? I have a set of variable `x_{1},...,x_{n}` and some constraints.  now I have some constraints whose are valid under some circumstances. for example if  `x_{1}+...+x_{n}=kn+1` where `k is an integer then constraint A is valid.
is there any way that I can write it in ampl?

In other words the problem is that I want to search layer by layer in feasible reign. the layer is dot product between a point x=(x1,...,xn) and the vector **1**=(1,1,1,...1) . 
so

if < x,**1**>=1     then x has to satisfy the constraint A<1,
if =2 then x has to satisfy the constraint B<2,
.
.
.
this is what I found in AMPL website but it does not work! (n is dimension of x and k arbitrary integer)

```
    subject to Time {if < x,1 > =kn+1}:

    s.t. S1: A<1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear whether your example means "constraint A requires that `x_[1]+...+x_[n]=4m+1` where `m` is an integer", or "if `x_[1]+...+x_[n]=4m+1` where `m` is an integer, then constraint A requires some other condition to be met".

The former is trivial to code:

```
var m integer;
s.t. c1: sum{i in 1..n} x_[i] = 4m+1;
```

It does require a solver with MIP capability. From your tags I assume you're using CPLEX, which should be fine.

For the latter: AMPL does have some support for logical constraints, documented [here](https://ampl.com/resources/logic-and-constraint-programming-extensions/). Depending on your problem, it's also sometimes possible to code logical constraints as linear integer constraints.

For example, if the `x[i]` variables in your example are also integers, you can set things up like so:

```
var m integer;
var r1 integer in 0..1;
var r2 integer in 0..2;
s.t. c1: r2 <= 2*r1; # i.e. r2 can only be non-zero if r1 = 1
s.t. c2: sum{i in 1..n} x_[i] = 4m+r1+r2;
var remainder_is_1 binary;
s.t. c3: remainder_is_1 >= r1-r2;
s.t. c4: remainder_is_1 <= 1-r2/2;
```

Taken together, these constraints ensure that `remainder_is_1` equals 1 if and only if `sum{i in 1..n} x_[i] = 4m+1` for some integer m. You can then use this variable in other constraints. This sort of trick can be handy if you only have a few logical constraints to deal with, but if you have many, it'll be more efficient to use the logical constraint options if they're available to you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. first of all I meant: if x_[1]+...+x_[n]=4m+1 where m is an integer, then constraint A requires some other condition to be met". Also suppose I have n constraints: A,B,C,D,E,F,.. then if x_[1]+...+x_[n]=4m+1 then A should be satisfied, if x_[1]+...+x_[n]=4m+2 then B should be satisfied , if x_[1]+...+x_[n]=4m+3 then C should be satisfied and so on. Now I dont know how I can code these!! could you please help me out?

Comment: @sherek_66 I already linked to the AMPL documentation which discusses how to use "if" constraints. If that doesn't answer your question, can you please edit the question to clarify where you're having trouble?

Comment: I just wrote the code with the help of that link, could you please help me out to correct it? thanks

Comment: @sherek_66 It's not clear from your post what the issue is or what you're trying to do.

Comment: @sherek_66 not really, sorry :-( I suggest reading the advice on creating a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).